# cPickle exceptions.EOFError in python

Tags: python-2.7, pickle

I tried to run this code in python but it gives me an exceptions.EOFError. Can you tell me why? Thanks to any replies

```
f = gzip.open('../data/mnist.pkl.gz', 'rb')
training_data, validation_data, test_data=cPickle.load(f)
f.close()
return (training_data, validation_data, test_data)
```